# IE11 message bar flies up from bottom instead of easing in from top

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

I have a message bar that is hidden unless the server responds with a message to render something (e.g. "The password and username are invalid."). Then it eases in from the top to display the message.

In latest versions of Chrome, Edge, Safari, and Firefox, this is working fine. In IE, it flies up from the bottom of the browser, across the viewing area, and then mounts where it should be when it is viewable.

This is the Sass that I have. I've been toying with the `transform` and `transition` to get the correct results, without affecting other browsers. I not been able to, so looking for suggestions:

```
#messages {
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

    .container {
        max-width: 890px;

        @media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px) {
            max-width: 720px;

        }

        @media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
            max-width: 510px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
        }
    }

    a {
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    i {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }

    .hide-messages-bar {
        color: #FFF;
        position: relative; 
        top: 105px;
        transform: translateY(-5vh);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;   
        box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 2px #333        
    }

    .hide-messages-bar.show-success-messages-bar {
        background-color: $green;                
        transform: translateY(0vh);
        padding: 8px 0;
    }

    .hide-messages-bar.show-error-messages-bar {
        background-color: $red;                
        transform: translateY(0vh);
        padding: 8px 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like there is an IE specific bug using vw and vh units in transformations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454352/2d-transform-transition-dosent-work-with-vw-and-vh-units-in-ie11

Comment: You may be able to get away with percentage units instead, depending on the positioning and size of your container element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arbuthnott got me pointed in the right direction. It turns out `px` works as well so I used that instead. Was having a hard time getting `%` to behave the same as it did in other browsers.

Used this tool to translate `vh` to `px`:

https://jsfiddle.net/Dwaaren/j9zahaLL/

And ended up with this:

```
.hide-messages-bar {
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative; 
    top: 105px;
    transform: translateY(-22.3px);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;   
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 2px #333        
}
```

The `0vh` on the other two classes apparently wasn't doing anything so left that as is. Now all major browsers perform similarly.